# vim: visual star search not working as expected

Tags: vim

I copied this function to visually search with `*` and `#`:

```
function! s:VSetSearch(cmdtype)
  let temp = @s
  norm! gv"sy
  let @/ = '\V' . substitute(escape(@s, a:cmdtype.'\'), '\n', '\\n', 'g')
  let @s = temp
endfunction

xnoremap * :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch('/')<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>
xnoremap # :<C-u>call <SID>VSetSearch('?')<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>
```

The `#` mapping works fine but the `*` mapping doesn't exit visual selection (it extends the range of the visual selection until the next searched word). I don't understand why this is happening. Is there a solution?

**EDIT:** To reproduce the problem save the code snippet, download the [MS Installer](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/pc/gvim74.exe), open `cmd.exe` and start vim `vim -u NONE`, then do `:set nocp` and finally source the saved code. In fact, the following simple mapping doesn't work either:

```
nnoremap * *<C-o>
```

**EDIT 2:** Can someone else reproduce this issue? Should it be reported?

**EDIT 3:** I believe that the problem (bug?) is that the `*` (star) key cannot be remapped: if I start vim with `vim -N -u NONE` (Vim 7.4 with patches 1-274) and run the command `:noremap * :echo "star"<CR>` and press `*`, vim tries to perform a search. I also reported [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/nkcV51bsQuc) to the vim dev group.

Comment: Please do `:verbose vmap *` to make sure the mapping is setup correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "_search visually_"?

Comment: @jahroy Search for the Visual selection. The code is taken verbatim from https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-visual-star-search.

Comment: Maybe you should try adding the other two mappings from that page?

Comment: @jahroy The other two mappings are `<leader>*` mappings, so they do not apply here.

Comment: That's what I thought, but figured I'd throw it out there...

Comment: @PeterRincker `:verbose vmap *` returns  `:<C-u>call <SNR>1_VSetSearch('/')<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>` and `:verbose vmap #` returns  `:<C-u>call <SNR>1_VSetSearch('?')<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>`

Comment: @petobens I have saved your snippet of code and stared up vim via `vim -u NONE` and then sourced it (I also did `:set nocp`). The mappings worked as expected. Since `:vmap *` look to be correct. I can only assume a something much more subtle is going on. I would suggest you reduce your `~/.vimrc` until you get it to work properly.

Comment: @PeterRincker I repeated your procedure of starting with a blank vim and sourcing the function but I when I run the mapping I get an error `E488: Trailing characters`. I don't know if this changes something but I'm using MS Windows.

Comment: @PeterRincker The strange thing is that when I open gmvim with a  `vimrc` that is just `set nocp` and I try the mapping `nnoremap * *<C-o>` it doesn't work. Can you or someone reproduce this problem?

Comment: `E488: Trailing characters` is exactly as it sounds. One of your lines has trailing whitespace or altered in some way.

Comment: @PeterRincker I was testing it in Powershell and the mapping was not working properly. I've tried with `cmd.exe` and the problem persists (without the trailing error) i.e both the visual search and the mapping I added in my previous comment don't work. Is it a bug?

Comment: I have tested your code snippet. I personally use something very simple in my own vim setup. All without any issue. I would recommend you make sure you have latest installation of vim and start with a clean slate. I do not think this is a bug w/ vim nor do I think it is a bug with Drew Nelstrom's visual start search code.

Comment: @PeterRincker I tested again on another machine and the problem persists. See my updated question please.

Comment: @petobens Perhaps it's a Windows line endings problem? Have you tried `*` on a selection that has a following/preceding match in the same line (not crossing line boundaries)?

Comment: @glts Yes, I tried that and the problem still persists.

Comment: It works perfectly for me with no hassle.  Are you sure your problem isn't caused by bad newline characters?  If that's not the problem, maybe you copied an invalid quote character by using a Microsoft app or something... That seems to happen a lot to people who use Windows.

Comment: @jahroy Did you test it on Windows?

Comment: Yes.  I just tested it on Windows 7.  I'm using gVim.  I'll test it with normal Vim, too.... **I can reproduce your issue if I run Vim from the command line in Cygwin**.  When I run Vim from the command line **both** commands behave incorrectly: both `#` and `*` (note: I'm using Cygwin, not the DOS prompt).

Comment: @jahroy both commands behave incorrectly for me too. Does the `nnoremap * *<C-o>` mapping (or `nnoremap # #<C-o>`  work from the command line in Cygwin? They don't work on the DOS prompt.

Comment: All of my testing involves launching gVim or Vim from the commandline **in Cygwin**.  If I use gVim, the commands work properly.  If I use normal Vim (non-GUI vim), I reproduce your issue.  I have **not** tried to run Vim or gVim from DOS.  I know this isn't what you want to hear, but why not use gVim?  It's awesome in every way.

Comment: @jahroy I use gVim but for some reason when I start gVim with a `vimrc` that contains just `set nocompatible` and then I run the command `:nnoremap * *<C-o>` I don't get the expected behaviour. At the same time the visual search mapping doesn't work with `*`. I have no idea why this is happening since both mappings work with `#`. Thanks for all the testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping `<kMultiply>` instead of `*` solved the problem. Really strange since I do not use the keypad multiply key.

Answer (score 1):

The following is what I use :

```
function! s:Vword()
  return getline('.')[col("'<")-1:col("'>")-1]
endfunction

xnoremap <silent> * <Esc>/\v<<C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR>><CR>
xnoremap <silent> g* <Esc>/\v<C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR><CR>

xnoremap <silent> # o<Esc>?\v<<C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR>><CR>
xnoremap <silent> g# o<Esc>?\v<C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR><CR>

nnoremap <silent> g// :grep -w <cword> <C-R>=getcwd()<CR><CR>
nnoremap <silent> g/* :grep <cword> <C-R>=getcwd()<CR><CR>

xnoremap <silent> g// :<C-U>grep -w <C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR> <C-R>=getcwd()<CR><CR>
xnoremap <silent> g/* :<C-U>grep <C-R>=<SID>Vword()<CR> <C-R>=getcwd()<CR><CR>
```

I have also additionally added nice mappings for <kbd>g*</kbd> & similarly <kbd>g#</kbd> and also a bunch of mappings for invoking grep that I find very useful.

Edit: minor fixes to code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My real problem is that vim won't allow me to remap the star key. If you are on a Windows machine, can you test what I say in `Edit 3`? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not on windows unfortunately, however I have no reason to believe that should be the problem. Try to check using `verbose xmap *` and see if it's set to something other than what you've set, possibly another plugin is overriding it. If that is the case you have 2 options. 1. Delete the plugin, 2. put your code in a `.vim/after/plugin/visual_search.vim` and it should override the plugins mappings.

Comment: I'm starting vim with `-u NONE` flag so there is no plugin at all. I hope someone else reproduce this behavior. Thanks anyway.