# vim: complete depending on previous character

Tags: vim

I want to create a mapping that will changed the ins-completion depending on the character just before the cursor. If the character is `{` then I want tag completion, if its `:` i want normal completion (that depends on the complete option) and if the characters is a backslash plus some word (`\w+`) I want dictionary completion. I have the following in my `ftplugin/tex/latex_settings.vim` file:

```
setlocal dictionary=$DOTVIM/ftplugin/tex/tex_dictionary
setlocal complete=.,k
setlocal tags=./bibtags;

function! MyLatexComplete()
    let character = strpart(getline('.'), col('.') - 1, col('.'))

    if character == '{'
        return "\<C-X>\<C-]>"
    elseif character == ':'
        return "\<C-X>\<C-N>"
    else
        return "\<C-X>\<C-K>"
    endif
endfunction

inoremap <C-n> <c-r>=MyLatexComplete()<CR>
```

This doesn't work and I don't know how to fix it.

**Edit:** This seems to work but I'm want a conditional that checks for \w+ (backslash plus any word) and a final one that gives a message "No match found".

```
function! MyLatexComplete()
    let line = getline('.')
    let pos = col('.') - 1

    " Citations (comma for multiple ones)
    if line[pos - 1] == '{' || line[pos - 1] == ','
        return "\<C-X>\<C-]>"
    " Sections, equations, etc
    elseif line[pos - 1] == ':'
        return "\<C-X>\<C-N>"
    else
    " Commands (such as \delta)
        return "\<C-X>\<C-K>"
    endif
endfunction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your original function you have mistakes:

1. `strpart()` takes string, offset and **length** arguments, while you supplied two offsets.
2. `col('.')` is one character *past* the end-of-line. I.e. `len(getline('.'))==col('.')+1` meaning that `strpart(getline('.'), col('.')-1)` is always empty.

You have fixed these issues in the second variant. But if you want conditional check for `\command` you need not just last character. Thus I would suggest matching slice

```
let line=getline('.')[:col('.')-2]
if line[-1:] is# '{' || line[-1:] is# ','
   return "\<C-X>\<C-]>"
elseif line[-1:] is# ':'
   return "\<C-X>\<C-N>"
elseif line =~# '\v\\\w+$'
   return "\<C-X>\<C-K>"
else
   echohl ErrorMsg
       echomsg 'Do not know how to complete: use after {, comma or \command'
   echohl None
   return ''
endif
```

. Note some things:

1. Never use `==` for string comparison without `#` or `?` attached. This does not matter in this case, but you should make yourself used. `==#` and `==?` both ignore value of `'ignorecase'` setting (first acts as if `'noignorecase'` was set, second as if `'ignorecase'` was set). I use even stricter `is#`: `a is# b` is like `type(a)==type(b) && a ==# b`.
2. Same for `=~`: use `=~#`.
3. Due to backwards compatibility `string[-1]` (`string[any_negative_integer]`) is always empty. Thus I have to use `line[-1:]`.
4. Never use plain `:echoerr`. It is unstable: in terms that you cannot say for sure whether or not this will break execution flaw (`:echoerr` breaks execution if put inside `:try` block and does not do so otherwise). `echohl ErrorMsg|echomsg …|echohl None` never breaks execution, `throw …` and `try|echoerr …|endtry` break always.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer and an excellent and detailed explanation. One minor question, how can you modify the "command" regex so it will work with just "\"  and also with "\\\w+"?

Comment: @petobens Use `\\\w*` as a regular expression then.

Comment: I believe you are an active member of the Vim Dev. Do you happen to know if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387991/vim-visual-star-search-not-working-as-expected) is a bug and should be reported?

Answer (score 1):

To spot preceding LaTeX commands you can use the following regular expression on your `line` variable:

```
line =~ '\\\w\+$'
```

(as you can see, the regex is similar to the Perl expression you guessed at, but requires some the characters to be escaped).

To echo a `"No match found"` message, you could return an appropriate `:echoerr` command:

```
return "\<C-o>:echoerr 'No match found'\<CR>"
```

But this has the side-effect of hijacking insert-mode for a moment... maybe it's cleaner just to return no matches as an empty string?

So your final function would look something like this:

```
function! MyLatexComplete()
    let line = getline('.')
    let pos = col('.') - 1

    " Citations (comma for multiple ones)
    if line[pos - 1] == '{' || line[pos - 1] == ','
        return "\<C-X>\<C-]>"
    " Sections, equations, etc
    elseif line[pos - 1] == ':'
        return "\<C-X>\<C-N>"
    elseif line =~ '\\\w\+$'
    " Commands (such as \delta)
        return "\<C-X>\<C-K>"
    else
    " Echo an error:
        return "\<C-o>:echoe 'No match found'\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: You have two mistakes here: 1. It is not guaranteed that completion will happen at the end of line. Thus matching `line` against `\\\w\+$` is incorrect. 2. `:echoe` should not be used, explanation is in my answer.