# vim: cannot remap star key

Tags: vim

When trying to fix the issue reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387991/vim-visual-star-search-not-working-as-expected) I found that the real problem is that I cannot remap the star key `*` using a Windows PC and Vim 7.4 with patches 1-274: if I start vim with `vim -N -u NONE`  and run the command `:noremap * :echo "star"<CR>` and press `*`, vim tries to perform a search instead of echoing "star".  Running `:verbose map *` however correctly returns `:echo "star"<CR>`.

Can someone reproduce this behavior? Is there a workaround? I also reported [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/nkcV51bsQuc)
to the vim dev group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping `<kMultiply>` instead of `*` solved the problem. Really strange since I do not use the keypad multiply key.

Comment: Oh gosh. Thank you! I was having the same issue on a Ubuntu gVim (not Vim though).